# Configure log4j2 in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, log4j, log4j2

How can I get Eclipse plugin to recognize log4j2.xml configuration file? File will be bundled into plugin jar so I cannot rely upon it being on file system. With log4j 1.2, I was able to achieve this in `Activator.start(BundleContext)` method via a call to `PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().getResource("/log4j.properties"))`. log4j2 seems to have nuked that method.

Calling `System.setProperty(ConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY, "/log4j2.xml")` or using
`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/log4j2.xml` runtime param violate constraints outlined above. I need a solution that will work within the context of Eclipse plugin architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The log4j2 team are currently working on OSGi improvements and this and any other feedback will be very valuable. Please consider raising this on the log4j2 issue tracker or the log4j-dev or log4j-user mailing lists.

Comment: Can you supply an issue number to follow up? Or are there any news about this?